# Django datetime field prints out unsupported operand type error

Tags: python, django, datetime

I have a `@property` in my django model which prints out `True` or `False` based on datetime difference. Even though it works when I am unittesting it I get error

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.datetime' and 'datetime.date'
```

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    ...
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    
    @property
    def is_expired(self):
        if datetime.now(tz=utc) - self.created_at > timedelta(hours=48):
            return True
        return False
```

How do I fix this? Every answer I checked does not help me .

Comment: Are you sure type of created_at is datetime?

Comment: I am sure yes..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The traceback error is explaining the problem to you:

> unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.datetime' and 'datetime.date'

This says that you cannot subtract a `datetime.datetime` from a `datetime.date`. In your case, `self.created_at` appears to be a `date` but your use of `datetime.now()` and `timedelta()` suggest that you really want to be dealing with `datetime`s.

Therefore, the solution is to either

1. make sure that `created_at` is a `datetime`, or
2. change `datetime.now()` to `date.today()` and change `timedelta(hours=48)` to `timedelta(days=2)`

These will behave a little differently so pick one depending on whether things expire after two calendar days or in 48 hours.

Comment: How can I change `created_at` so it could match datetime.now() ? Change its format maybe somehow..

Comment: From your question edit, it looks like created_at should be a datetime. Could there be a database migration you haven't applied or something?